# Usage of "in hint"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

The [news](https://www.express.co.uk/sport/tennis/1700560/Novak-Djokovic-Rafael-Nadal-Roger-Federer-snub-comparisons-Carlos-Alcaraz-tennis-news) title writes

> Novak Djokovic, Rafa Nadal and Roger Federer snubbed **in hint** comparisons insult Alcaraz

I think the title means

> (The fact that) Novak Djokovic, Rafa Nadal and Roger Federer (are) snubbed (in the claim made by Mats Wilander) **hints that** comparisons insult Alcaraz.

But what does **in hint** mean here? The grammar and usage is pretty strange to me though I could intuitively understand what it should mean. Can anyone make another example sentence with in hint?

Comment: This is journalese: the normal rules of grammar doe not apply.

Comment: Even for journalese this is impressively unintelligible.

Comment: The only way I can make any sense of it is "ND. RN and RF [are] snubbed in [a] hint [that] comparisons [with them] insult A,"

Answer (score 2):

The title sentence means "Novak Djokovic, Rafa Nadal and Roger Federer have been snubbed by Mats Wilander's hint that trying to compare them to Alcaraz is an insult to Alcaraz."

Hint here is being used as a noun;

> something that you say or do that shows what you think or want, usually in a way that is not direct

as [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hint) puts it.

Be aware that newspaper headlines often break rules of grammar to make a shorter, snappier title. You shouldn't ever write like this yourself (unless you're writing a newspaper headline). If you wanted a similar construction, you could say something like "CEO's remark worries investors in hint that tomorrow's shareholder meeting will be a stormy one" or "PM embarrassed in statement by top civil servant" or what have you.